# Does the Double Slit Experiment Violate Physics

Tags: gravity, experimental-physics

I am probably going to butcher this questions so don't flame me for it.

If I have an electron and I shoot it at the double slit.  Or even better a LOT of electrons and I am shooting them at the double slit.  I get the known pattern on the detector after the slits.  But doesn't this violate physics?  Each electron has a certain mass and gravity that is a part of it. How can the mass and gravity pass through 2 slits and then recombine into a single electron to hit and form the pattern?

Comment: It’s a famous experiment discussed in almost every quantum physics textbook, so it seems strange that you think it “violates physics” in any way. What it violates is everyone’s *intuitions* about physics.

Comment: The trick is in your last sentence - the electron doesn’t become two and then recombine. The same electron goes through both slits. Or, more properly, the one electron wave function goes through both slits.

Comment: The only way to "violate physics" is to.be wrong.

Comment: Don't just go by feelings. The Question is not that Bad. Even this argument was taken in context by Barton zweibach at MIT in lecture of Quantum Physics

Comment: I was thinking of the electron as a particle with mass and gravity....

Answer (score 2):

No. Physics is not violated. Think of the particle as a wave during the two-slit experiment. There is a wave/particle duality, depending on the experiment you do. If you try to measure a wave, you will get a result consistent with a wave. If try to measure a particle, you will get a result consistent with a particle. The only thing that appears to be violated, is our understanding of nature.

Answer (score 0):

No, It doesn't violate laws of physics, it violates your Inbuilt Intuition.

It's not like that something is either wave or particle. It's like when you wanted to see its wave character in experiments you will find behaving it like waves. (like do interference with electron). There is a formula for interference, you know that and in place of wavelength, you can put h/p and you will get your calculations consistent with results. Now Place a detector, you will get particle character. (It's weird!). But true

But why it showed the particle character now? Because by placing the detector you wanted to find which particle passed through which hole in an interference experiment. So you wanted to see its particle character, show it showed you.

In a wave, there is no notion that this wave passed through this hole or like this

Don't confuse it with the trivial intuition of the wave. it's far more than that, far different than that. But, anyway, the question is not about this.